# how to receive values by POST method without using HTML Forms

Tags: php, api, http-post

I have php API but When a value is sent without an Html form (POST), it returns a null result.

How do I get the query (POST method) from the header?

`$_POST[""]` retern null.

I used this too:

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Method,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Athorization,X-Requested-With");
```

I POST the values to the api with this method:

```
$url = "api url";

//The data you want to send via POST
$fields = [
    'mobile '      => 'value',
    'intcode' => 'value'
];

$postdata = http_build_query($fields);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
To solve this problem I need to get the data via RAW.
PHP: Receive raw POST data.

`$postBody = file_get_contents("php://input");`

[A complete explanation is given in the link below.](https://thisinterestsme.com/php-receive-raw-post-data/)